# SQL Select from table twice

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to select from the same table twice within SQL.

I have a POLICIES table that has an index (NEXTPOLICYID) that refers to itself.

I need to compare the current premium with the estimated premium.

How can I get a result that shows the following on the same result row?

t1 = Current
t2 = Future

```
End result should be:

t1.POLICIES_ID | t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM | t2.POLICIES_ID | t2.ESTIMATED_PREMIUM
```

This is what I have right now, and I am getting an error on my join statement, but I fear that is not my only problem.

```
SELECT 
    t1.POLICIES_ID, t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM, t1.NEXTPOLICYID, t2.ESTIMATED_PREMIUM
FROM 
    POLICIES t1 JOIN
    POLICIES t2
    ON t1.NEXTPOLICYID = t2.POLICIES_ID
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Rocket U2][UVODBC][1401233]Error ID: 29 Severity: ERROR Facility: FPSRVERR - Line 5, column 17 (around "JOIN"): Syntax error., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect
```

This is an ODBC Connection to a uniVerse database, I have tested this with many other functions and it works fine.  This error tells me it does not like something before the JOIN statement.

Thank you

Comment: Also add a comma after `t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the comma, the only other issues are:

- You don't need to include `t2.POLICIES_ID` in the `select` list, because you have `t1.NEXTPOLICYID`
- You might want to consider a `left outer join`, to keep policies that have no next policy.

The query might be:

```
 SELECT t1.POLICIES_ID, t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM, t1.NEXTPOLICYID,
        t2.ESTIMATED_PREMIUM
 FROM POLICIES t1 JOIN
      POLICIES t2
      ON t1.NEXTPOLICYID = t2.POLICIES_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have revised my SQL and I am still getting an error; any thoughts?

Comment: I am fairly confident the issue has to do with me using an ODBC connection.  I tested this out directly in MSSMS with another database and it worked fine.  Maybe the SQL structure is slightly different and requires different syntax?

Comment: @evade . . . Does it still have the problem if you specify `inner join` explicitly?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your solution worked fine in a similar test case scenario outside of my current project.  The real issue was the limitation set in place by my ODBC driver provided.  It simply does not support some of the SQL functions.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SELECT
    t1.POLICIES_ID,
    t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM
    t1.NEXTPOLICYID,
    t2.ESTIMATED_PREMIUM,
    t2.POLICIES_ID
FROM 
    POLICIES t1,
    JOIN POLICIES t2 ON t1.NEXTPOLICYID = t2.POLICIES_ID
```

has some issues with commas in the wrong places and should be:

```
SELECT
    t1.POLICIES_ID,
    t1.WRITTEN_PREMIUM,
    t1.NEXTPOLICYID,
    t2.ESTIMATED_PREMIUM,
    t2.POLICIES_ID
FROM 
    POLICIES t1
    JOIN POLICIES t2 ON t1.NEXTPOLICYID = t2.POLICIES_ID
```

I'm guessing that's the reason for the error.